# React jest how to test Redirect based on localStorage item

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component which checks for a local-storage key and based on that it decides whether to render component or redirect to login screen.

I want to test this case using jest and enzyme but i am not able to force code to use mock localstorage and not actual browser locastorage.

Right now code it trying to read localstorage and it always gets null value.

I have already spent 2-3 hours and followed many stackobverflow question but most of them are trying to mock localstorage and checking if it sets and reads values from fake localstorage.

I think my case is different because i want to fake localstorage but that output should affect component decision.

Below is my component code

```
        // Below console.log prints null when i run test, which i think should print { "googleId" : null} , isnt it ?
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("auth")); 
        let storageUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth"));
        if (!storageUser || !storageUser.googleId){
            return <Redirect to="/login" />
        }

        return (
            <Home user  = {user} />
        )
    }
```

and my test code

```
it("Renders Home page if googleId is set in localStorage", () => {
    const localStorage = jest.fn();
    global.localStorage.getItem = key => '{ "googleId" : null}';

    // Below code prints { "googleId" : null}
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("auth"));

    expect(wrapper.find(Home).length).toEqual(1);
});
```

Comment: Anyone there :( ??

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [**jest-localstorage-mock**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-localstorage-mock) - the setup process shouldn't be tough.

By including the package in your tests, you have access to a mocked LS that can be manipulated with ease, for instance:

```
localStorage.__STORE__["auth"] = your_desired_object;
```

Here is a brief example that might fit your issue - and also it's a demonstration of testing the different conditionals in cases like this:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
   // According to the documentation: "values stored in tests will also be available in other tests unless you run"
   localStorage.clear();
});

describe("when `auth` does not exist in the localStorage", () => {
   it("redirects the user to the `login` page", () => {
      // ...
   });
});

describe("when `auth` exists in the localStorage", () => {
   describe("when `googleId` is not defined", () => {
      it("redirects the user to the `login` page", () => {
         // ...
      });
   });

   describe("when `googleId` is defined", () => {
      it("renders `Home`", () => {
        // Ensures if the `Home` page is rendered if the last circumstance occurs.
      });
   });
});
```